# In which directory does prometheus stores metric in linux environment?

Tags: kubernetes, curl, prometheus, metrics

I am using kubernetes pod (ubuntu base image) and within that prometheus pod metrics are getting emitted.
These metrics are getting displayed on terminal using:

```
curl -v http://localhost:5000/metrics
```

I am unable to find any prometheus.yml file or any conf file in /etc directory of the pod.
Please help me in getting the file location where I will be able to view the metrics and use it  further.

Comment: You need to scrape this metrics endpoint using a Prometheus instance. Either installed on another Linux server, or with a Helm chart on Kubernetes, or you can just use the Grafana cloud agent if you don't want overhead and don't have a lot of metrics (it will send the metrics to grafana Cloud): https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/agent/

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Kubernetes resources expose an endpoint for Prometheus to collect metrics, but Prometheus is not installed by default.

So to use the metrics further you would have to install Prometheus. This can be easily done on the cluster using a Helm chart or a Kubenetes manifest found with a quick google.

I would recommend using [Promethus Operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator) which also enables a Grafana instance where you can visualise a lot of the metrics that is collected from your pod.